# jQuery doesn't output proper HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very old Rails 3 project I'm maintaining, to which I need to add new functionality. Primarily responsiveness with Bootstrap 4.

This is what I actually want to create: http://jsfiddle.net/k1zbe4o9/. As you can see it works perfectly in the fiddle. However this project uses jQuery to dynamically change HTML. The jQuery code is fairly simple

```
if (best_price) {
  li_class = "list-group-item";
  li_class += " card-list-best";
}
```

I use this in function like so:

```
var list_html = $("<li class=" + li_class + ">" + list_details_html + "</li>");
```

However, when I do this I get this weird thing that the jQuery doesn't return this properly, so instead of having `list-group-item card-list-best` inside a single `<li>` class, somehow I get `card-list-best` outside that scope, and the result is as shown.

The same thing happens if I do:

```
if (best_price) {
  li_class = "list-group-item card-list-best";
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image: jquery segment]

Comment: why are you using jQuery for this?

Comment: The problem is because of the spaces in the class attribute you're trying to set. You need to wrap the entire attribute value in quotes for the space to be respected within the value. This isn't a jQuery issue, it's part of the HTML standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `'` when you build the `li`.

```
"<li class='" + li_class + "'>" + list_details_html + "</li>"
```

as you can see in the example, I've added a console log, it returns `<li class=list-group-item card-list-best>test</li>` so if there no `"` or `'` after `class=` then it will take the value after `=` and until the first space, so it would return `<li class="list-group-item">test</li>`

**Working example**

```js
var li_class = "";
var list_details_html = "test";
li_class = "list-group-item";
li_class += " card-list-best";
var list_html = $(
  "<li class='" + li_class + "'>" + list_details_html + "</li>"
);

console.log("<li class=" + li_class + ">" + list_details_html + "</li>")

$('ul').append(list_html)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```